# Disable double x shortcut in Prelude

Tags: key-bindings, prelude

I have setup prelude and the setup is just great. There is one thing that bothers me: whenever I type double x, emacs opens *helm-mode-execute-extended-command*.

Is there a way to disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
(key-chord-define-global "xx" nil)
```

You can add it to your personal configuration file. This has been described in Prelude's [README](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#key-chords).